# Prove that if rank $(\begin{smallmatrix} A &B\\ C&D\end{smallmatrix})=\operatorname{rank}(A)$, then $D=CA^{-1}B$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an invertible $n \times n$ matrix with entries from a field $F$. Prove that if rank $\begin{pmatrix} A &B\\ C&D\end{pmatrix}=\operatorname{rank}(A)$, then $D=CA^{-1}B$ .

Comment: Please add your thoughts/partial work when you ask a question, in order for us to help you more specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

It is easy to show
$$\begin{bmatrix}
A&B\\
C&D
\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}
A&0\\
0&D-CA^{-1}B
\end{bmatrix}$$
so we have
$${\rm rank}\begin{bmatrix}
A&B\\
C&D
\end{bmatrix}={\rm rank}(A)+{\rm rank}{(D-CA^{-1}B)}$$
and hence
$$\rm{rank(D-CA^{-1}B)}=0$$
then you can solve your problem

Comment: Possibly this is even more difficult to prove than OP's question?

Comment: No,I fell this method also not hard

Comment: I don't get how the top right corner becomes zero. Why wouldn't the top left corner become something like $A-BD^{-1}C$ if you want the top right corner to be zero?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Using block row operations, write the matrix as a product of two block triangular matrices, one of which is invertible. (To get an idea of what the operation should be, pretend first that $a, b, c, d$ are all scalars and determine what row operation would eliminate $c$. Then perform the analogous operation, but by blocks.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "blocks"

Comment: @tink : "Blocks" are what $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are.  I.e. smaller matrices stacked up in an array for form a larger matrix. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @tink Blocks are what Michael Hardy said they are. My suggested solution uses something called "block multiplication" of matrices. If you don't know about that, then this solution won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way.

Note that $\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ -C A^{-1} & I \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & -CA^{-1}B+D \end{bmatrix}$. The first matrix is invertible,
so the rank of the last matrix is the same as the rank of the middle matrix.

We are given that the rank of the middle matrix is the same as the rank
of $A$, hence we must have $-CA^{-1}B+D = 0$, otherwise the rank of the
last matrix would be strictly greater than the rank of $A$.